# How to create a binary stream (not a file) in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, binarystream

I have a function which output some binary data to a stream. But the stream is abstract, which means the stream can be a file stream, or some other streams. But the stream must be a binary stream which support write-byte function. I searched but not found the answer.

What I want to do is, I have a function which will convert some data to a gif. But I donot want to output the data to a file, I want to output it to something in memory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [flexi-streams](http://weitz.de/flexi-streams/) library provides, among other things, in-memory binary streams.

Comment: "It also supplies in-memory binary streams which are similar to string streams. " seems it's what i want. I'll read the documentation for more information. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, with-output-to-sequence in flexi-streams solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

"File in memory" - is just a byte array. So all you need is to read your data from stream and write it to one-dimensional array (vector). For more information on arrays in CL see [this](http://www.ida.liu.se/imported/cltl/clm/node157.html).

Comment: No, that's not what i want. What i want is write some data to an array(or something else). But the 'write' function needs a stream object. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @kevin lynx: So what's the problem to create this function? Read all bytes from stream to a list and supply this list as `:initial-contents` to `make-array`.