# How to create a bidirectional binary stream in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I read [How to create a binary stream (not a file) in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441992/how-to-create-a-binary-stream-not-a-file-in-common-lisp), and it describes how to create a binary stream but not a bidirectional one. I've attempted to do it myself using the library referenced, but failed. My attempt looks like:

```
(defun make-test-binary-stream ()
  (make-two-way-stream (flexi-streams:make-in-memory-input-stream 
                         (vector))
   (flexi-streams:make-in-memory-output-stream)))
```

I use it like:

```
(let ((str (make-test-binary-stream))) 
   (lisp-binary:write-float :double 123.45d0 :stream str) 
   (lisp-binary:read-binary-type 'double-float str))
```

The result I'd expect there is `123.45d0`, but instead it returns `0.0d0`.

How could I create a binary stream that behaves as I expect, allowing me to write a value in then read the same value back? I want such a stream for testing the correctness of encoding and decoding functions that take streams as input and output to streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A two-way stream `S` is a couple `(I,O)` where `I` is an input stream and `O` an output stream. Both streams are not necessarily related, it just means that when you read from `S`, you read from `I`, and when you write to `S`, you write to `O`.

Here, you try to read from an in-memory stream that is backed by an empty sequence. The stream just gives the items in the sequence, but as a stream; here, the stream reaches end-of-file immediately.

#### Anonymous buffer

Not directly answering the question, but I sometimes use *lisp-binary* and the way I test is as follows:

```
(with-input-from-sequence 
    (in (with-output-to-sequence (out)
          (write-float :double 123.45d0 :stream out)))
  (read-binary-type 'double-float in))
```

Let's decompose:

```
(flex:with-output-to-sequence (out)
  (write-float :double 123.45d0 :stream out))
```

The above locally bind `out` to a stream that writes into a hidden, in-memory sequence, and eventually return that sequence. The whole expression returns a buffer of bytes:

```
#(205 204 204 204 204 220 94 64)
```

This buffer is given to `with-input-from-sequence` to bind `in` to a local stream that reads data from that sequence. `read-binary-type` uses that input stream to decode the value.

#### Temporary file

```
(defpackage :so (:use :cl :lisp-binary :flexi-streams :osicat))
(in-package :so)
```

The *osicat* system has a macro to open a temporary file in both input and output mode:

```
(with-temporary-file (io :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (write-float :double pi :stream io)
  (file-position io 0)
  (read-binary-type 'double-float io))
```

#### In memory circular buffer

I couldn't find an existing implementation of an in-memory i/o stream that reads and writes from/to the same vector; you can hack something with two *flexi-streams* that share an internal vector (but this is dangerous, there are cases where data consistency breaks), or built one from gray streams; see also [cl-stream](https://github.com/cl-stream/cl-stream).